# The length of 4th element of array shows 24 while it has just the word "spain"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to compare the 5th element of my array with the value of the object which is clicked,
Here is my code :

```js
var options = new Array();

$(".option").click(function compareReaction(name) {
  var classname1 = ($(this).parent().attr('class').slice(7));
  var arr = new Array();
  i = 1
  var text_val
  while (i <= 5) {
    text_val = $('.' + classname1).children('.o' + (i)).text();
    arr.push(text_val);
    i++;
  }
  alert(arr);
  var result = arr[4];
  alert(result.length);
  alert(name);
  var name1 = "spain";
  if (result == 'spain') {
    alert("oh yeahhhh!");
  } else {
    alert("oh no");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 option o<%= k %>" onclick="compareReaction(name=(this).innerHTML)">
```

Now here the length of the result is 24 while its just 'spain' word in it so it should be 5 and also if I alert the onclick action it displays the class name which I want to send but somehow it is not passing it to the compareReaction so if I alert name it displays (object, object) rather it should alert the classname.

Comment: You've not defined the `compareReaction()` function anywhere. You also have several syntax issues with the arguments you use in the call

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please tell me where I am wrong exactly and why is the length of arr[4] is 24 rather it should be 5 because it has word spain , i have tried removing the white spaces but still its showing 24 characters.

Comment: Is your snippet supposed to run? I only get a blank area.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález no actually I am coding in rails and everything is stiched to the server response , My answer was edited and snippet was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was, I had to trim the element while i was pushing into the array and secondly I was following a wrong approach i had to use event target to get the value of the div clicked so my code looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( ".option" ).click(function (e) {
var name=$(e.target).text().trim();;
//var name = $(e.target).innerHTML().trim();
  var classname1 = ($(this).parent().attr('class').slice(7));
  var arr = new Array();
  i = 1
  var text_val
  while(i <= 5){
   text_val = $('.'+classname1).children('.o'+(i)).text();
   arr.push(text_val.trim());
   i++;
  }
  // alert(arr);
  // var result = arr[4];
  // alert(result.length);
  // alert(name);
  if (result == name) {
    alert("oh yeahhhh!");
    }else{
        alert("oh no");
    }

});

</script>
```

Here is a working fiddle of it :
https://jsfiddle.net/gxenxbay/3/

hope it helps someone someday!